# Opensource XML Editor in Javascript (Use with in extjs Project)

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new to extjs , i need to know is there any good xml editor or viewer in extjs itself or any other Opensource XML Editor component in JavaScript is available to use along with extjs.

if possible pls provide samples or links also..

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any idea. Here are some pieces of code to begin yours:

Create your XMLDoc from String :

```
    function fromXMLToString(xmlString) {

        var xmlDoc = null;
        if (window.DOMParser) {
            var parser=new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(xmlString,"text/xml");
        }
        else // IE
        {
            xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async="false";
            xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlString); 
        }
        return xmlDoc;
    }

    var someXmlDoc = fromXMLToString("<a><b>1</b><b>2</b></a>") ;
```

Convert XMLDoc to string :

```
function fromStringToXML(xmlDoc){
    var xmlString = "";

    if (window.ActiveXObject){  // IE

        xmlString = xmlDoc.xml;
    }else{      // others

        xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDoc);
    }
    return xmlString;
}

var someXmlString = fromStringToXML(someXmlDoc);

alert(someXmlString);
```

Comment: I forgot ... once you get a XML object, you handle it exactly the same way you handle the document object. (getElementsByName, getElementsByTagNames ...)